# how to keep a window open while pressing a shortcut

Tags: i3-window-manager, i3

Is there anyway of making floating window show up while a shortcut is pressed and closing the window/application when the shortcut is released?

The goal of this is to make cheatsheets show up depending on a shortcut pressed